Woocommerce replace product image in single product page
I am trying to replace product image in single product page with video. I used this code, but the problem is that my video appears twice.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'replace_product_image_with_video', 10, 2 );
function replace_product_image_with_video( $html, $attachment_id ) {
global $product;
    $productID = $product->get_id();  // get current product ID
   // replace 11 to your specific product id 
     if( $productID == 11 ) {
         $html = '<iframe width="650" height="420" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5sLA74nAt0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
   }
   return $html;

}
I suspect this happens because default Wordpress theme I use has this code in /templates/single-product/product-thumbnails.php
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', wc_get_gallery_image_html( $attachment_id ), $attachment_id ); 

I dont want to overwrite this or create child themes. Is there a way to remove this filter with code somehow?

The problem occurs on products with multiple image, the scripts replace all the thumbnails with the video.
To show only one video, I added a condition to replace only the product featured image
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'replace_product_image_with_video', 10, 2 );
function replace_product_image_with_video( $html, $attachment_id ) {
global $product;
    $productID = $product->get_id();  // get current product ID
   // replace 11 to your specific product id 
     if( $productID == 11 && $attachment_id == $product->get_image_id() ) {
         $html = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><iframe width="650" height="420" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5sLA74nAt0"
       frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>';
   }
return $html;

Note that on the theme I use, I had to wrap the iFrame in a div otherwise it would be hidden.

You can easily take care of this by injecting a script to replace the image and then remove the video from the thumb without needing a child theme.
function add_custom_product_video_script() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var productID = <?php global $product; echo $product->get_id(); ?>;
                if (productID == 11) {
                    var videoHTML = '<iframe width="650" height="420" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5sLA74nAt0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                    $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__image').html(videoHTML);
                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_custom_product_video_script');

function remove_product_video_filter() {
    remove_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'replace_product_image_with_video', 10);
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_product_video_filter');

I know you didn't ask, but if you're planning to do this a lot (on several different products) and don't want to end up with spaghetti code, you should just set up a key:value pair for productIDs and the videoID and then parameterize the video ID as well since everything else should remain the same.
